# Incrementing a counter stored in a file using Python

Tags: python, file, io

I have this following code which writes data to a text file(.txt) using python
which holds the count.
code:

```
f_check = file("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt",'r')
f_data = f_check.read()
chk_data = int(f_data)
if(count > chk_data): 
   print (' ')
   print 'count increased to = ',  node_count
   print (' ')
   print 'previous count = ', chk_data
   print (' ')
   f1 = open("node_file.txt", "w")
   n1 = f1.write(str(count) + "\n")
   f1.close()
```

Problem : I already have data in the text file as '2'(count), next time when count increases according to logic (ex:- count increased to 3) it should write the data in it and save the same, but as of now it is not writing the increased count in the .txt file, does the above code needs any changes?

Comment: Try to close the file once you are done with reading, may be that helps.

Comment: OS doesn't matter here. Python is designed to be cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One noticeable issue is that you are not closing your file after reading from it.

I recommend you use a `with...as` context manager so you don't need to worry about closing files:

```
with open ("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    chk_data = int(f.read().strip())

if(count > chk_data): 
   with open("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt", "w") as f:
       f.write(str(count) + "\n")
```

Other minor changes involve stripping off `\n` from `f.read()` using `str.strip`.

Comment: but it doesn't overwrite the previous data with new one, anything else to add?

Comment: @Rebbeca Check your `count` variable. I guess the `if` is not executing.

Comment: @Rebbeca I also fixed the write path.

Comment: I get the following error :

chk_data = int(f.read().strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @Rebbeca Your file is empty. :/

Comment: Yes and it should not be empty right , the logic above should overwrite the previous value >> write the currrent value>> save the file ? isn't it?

Comment: Nopes, actually its an error which is most likely to be handled by exception handler, which I did and it worked, although my file was not empty the next time when it was updating the count it was giving the same error.
Thanks for you response coldspeed !! appreaciate it :-)

Comment: @Rebbeca Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to take care.

1.You are reading the file from `f_check = file("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt",'r')` and writing to `open("node_file.txt", "w")` . **Use absolute path for write**.

2. Use `with open('full path file', 'r') as f` type of style for file oporations.

Answer (score -1):

I think the file remains open, and you will not be able to write again in it when the count changes.

```
chk_data = None
with open("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt",'r') as f:
    chk_data = int(f.read())

if(count > chk_data): 
    print (' ')
    print 'count increased to = ',  node_count
    print (' ')
    print 'previous count = ', chk_data
    print (' ')
    with open("/home/ccheck/test/node_file.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(count) + "\n")
```

I did the following:

1. closed the file after reading / writing using context managers
2. changed to full path for both writing and reading to make sure the same file is used.